# Java.Nio.ByteBuffer to c#

Tags: c#, usb, bytebuffer

I am tring to use the following code in a c# xamarin project.

In Java,

```
ByteBuffer buffer=ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
UsbRequest request=new UsbRequest();
```

now I'm trying to convert these two line to c# for my xamarin project,

```
Java.Nio.ByteBuffer m_rinfo;
Int32 m_bytes = 64;
UsbRequest m_request = new UsbRequest();
m_request.Queue(m_rinfo, 64);<<error
```

The last line gives an error, "Use of assigned variable 'm_rinfo'

I've tried to assign bytes to m_rinfo with,

```
Java.Nio.ByteBuffer m_rinfo = new byte[64];
```

Which gives error, Cannot implicitly convert type byte

Any help would be appreciated.

I find I can convert the lines to;

```
Java.Nio.ByteBuffer m_rinfo = Java.Nio.ByteBuffer.Allocate(64);
Int32 m_bytes = 64;
UsbRequest m_request = new UsbRequest();
m_request.Queue(m_rinfo, 64);
```

However when the program gets to line;

```
 m_request.Queue(m_rinfo, 64);
```

I receive the error;

'Java.Lang.RuntimeException' was thrown

So what's wrong with this line?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `m_request.Queue(out m_rinfo, 64)`;? As far as I'm aware, `out` is used when a variable in c# is passed to a method with the intent of its value being changed within it. For example:

```
ListOfSomeKind list = null;
methodToFillListWithData(out list);
```